Let $T:\Bbb R^5\rightarrow\Bbb R^5$ be a $\Bbb R$ linear transformation.
Let $T:\Bbb R^5\rightarrow\Bbb R^5$ be a $\Bbb R$ linear transformation.Suppose that (1,-1,2,4,0),(4,6,1,6,0) and (5,5,3,9,0) span the null space of $T$.Which of the following statements are true?

$1$.The rank of $T$ is equal to $2$.$2$.Suppose that for every vector $v\in \Bbb R^5$,there exists $n$ s.t. $T^n(v)=0$.Then $T^2$ must be zero.$3$.Suppose that for every vector $v\in \Bbb R^5$,there exists $n$ s.t. $T^n(v)=0$.Then $T^3$ must be zero.$4$.(-2,-8,3,2,0) is contained in the null space of $T$.


Option(1): As the given set of vectors is linearly independent, the dimension of the null space of $T$ is $3$.Therefore, by the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the rank space of $T$ is $2$.Option(4): Since $2\times (1,-1,2,4,0)-(4,6,1,6,0)=(-2,-8,3,2,0)$.Therefore, $(-2,-8,3,2,0)$ is contained in null space of $T$.Now for the remaining options, we need to check if $T$ is a nilpotent operator either of index $2$ or index $3$.how to attempt options(2) and option(3)?

Try J....n form

Consider $S=T^n$ with $$S, : ,\operatorname{im}(T)\cong \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow {0}$$ with $n>1,$ i.e. the map that comes up after applying $T$ once. Now, assume the given conditions of 2) and 3).

Hint: $\operatorname{Null}(T^n) \subseteq \operatorname{Null}(T^{n+1})$ (why?) Then what could the dimensions of $\operatorname{Null}(T^2)$ and $\operatorname{Null}(T^3)$ be?

@MariusS.L. Sir can you please elaborate?

@aschepler is there any refrence for the proof of the result you have stated?

@aschepler nullity of $T^2$ and $T^3$ could be $3,4 or5$ and hence $T^2$ can not be a zero opearator but using this result one can not prove that $T^3=0$.

@SandeepTiwari We know that the rank of $T$ is two, i.e. the dimension of the image of $T$ is two. Hence we get a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^5\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2.$ If we apply $T$ for the second time, then it starts on the image of the first time, i.e. on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ So $T^2:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \ldots$ If additionally $T^n(v)=0$ for all $v$ and some $n,$ then $T^{2n}=0$ for some $n.$ But $T^2$ does not need to be zero, e.g. $T^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$ However, it must have a non-trivial nullspace. So what is left for $T^3$?

@MariusS.L.Then $T^{2n}=0$ for some $n$ then what is relation of $T^{2n}$ with $T^2$?Are you considering that some $n$ equal to $1$?

@SandeepTiwari $T^{2n}=0$ was only a hint that $T^2$ is still nilpotent and has therefore only zero eigenvalues. However, you did not say at which level I could answer, i.e. which level of technical terms you understand. That's why I kept it as simple as possible to the costs of winding sentences and avoided the words nilpotent and eigenvalue. The problem can be solved without them and without any calculations. Just note that $T^2$ acts on the image of $T$ which is $\mathbb{R}^2.$ My example of a matrix showed that this is not sufficient for $T^2=0.$ But it is sufficient for $T^3=0.$

@SandeepTiwari MSE is unfortunately not very good in teaching. It is made to solve questions. Tutoring is difficult here. There are better places.

@MariusS.L. Ok sir.Thank you for your valuable time and comments.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Assume these three linearly independent vectors as $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}$, then extend this basis of null space of $T$ to get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ and say basis vectors are $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}, e_{5}$.
Now consider a linear transformation,
$T(e_{i}) = 0 ~\forall 1 \leq i \leq 3 
\\ T(e_{4}) = e_{1}
\\ T(e_{5}) = e_{4}$
It is a nilpotent operator, such that $T^{2} \neq 0$ but $T^{3} = 0$. So, option (2) is not true.
Now if $T$ is nilpotent that is the case of option (2) & option(3), then consider an upper triangular matrix(We can consider that(Why?)) then as nilpotent matrix have only zero eigenvalues so we can assume that $T(e_{4}) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{3} a_{i}e_{i}$ and $T(e_{5}) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{4} b_{i}e_{i}$, where $a_{i}, b_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$.
Which implies $T^{2}(e_{4}) = 0$ and $T^{2}(e_{5}) = b_{4}T(e_{4})$ so $T^{3}(e_{5}) = 0$, which implies $T^{3} = 0$

T can be represented as an upper triangular matrix because $0$ is only eigen value of $T$ and $0\in\Bbb R$ and hence jordan canonical form of $T$ exist.Is my reasoning correct?

If you look at Jordan, then it's okay. Otherwise, you can reduce any matrix to a lower triangular matrix without changing the property, which is essential here. So basically, using that equivalent form that is easy to understand or express.

there must be some criteria to reduce a matrix in upper triangular form.

A real matrix is triangulable iff all of its eigenvslues are real.
